# How can I make the Docker provider in Terraform wait for an address to become available before attempting to connect to it?

Tags: terraform, terraform-remote-state, terraform-provider-docker

I have the following resource in Terraform:

```
provider "docker" {
    host = "tcp://${digitalocean_droplet.docker_server.ipv4_address}:2376/"
}
```

This relies on the value `ipv4_address` to be known before it can connect to the docker machine. This value is not known until another resource is provisioned:

```hcl
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "docker_server" {
    image = "docker-18-04"
    name = "docker_server"
    region = "nyc2"
    size = "512mb"
    private_networking = true
    ssh_keys = [
      var.ssh_fingerprint
    ]

    connection {
        user = "root"
        type = "ssh"
        private_key = file(var.pvt_key)
        timeout = "2m"
    }
}
```

When I run `terraform plan`, I get the following error:

> **Error:** Error initializing Docker client: unable to parse docker host
>   ``
>
> on docker.tf line 1, in provider "docker":    1: provider "docker" {

It appears that `ipv4_address` is empty because the docker plugin is trying to connect to the docker machine before it is provisioned. How do I tell it to wait for the machine to be provisioned before trying to connect to it?

---

#### One thing I tried:

```
provider "docker" {
    host = "tcp://${digitalocean_droplet.docker_server.ipv4_address}:2376/"
    depends_on = [
        digitalocean_droplet.docker_server.ipv4_address,
    ]
}
```

When I do that, I get this error:

> **Error:** Reserved argument name in provider block
>
> on docker.tf line 4, in provider "docker":    4:     depends_on = [
>
> The provider argument name "depends_on" is reserved for use by
>   Terraform in a future version.

But reading more into `depends_on`, I don't think that's the solution anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately a [provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html) block doesn't support [expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#references-to-resource-attributes) referring to a [resource attribute](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#resource-types-and-arguments).

This limitation is explained in the [provider configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#provider-configuration) documentation:

> The configuration arguments defined by the provider may be assigned using
>   expressions, which can for example allow them to be parameterized by input
>   variables.
>
> However, since provider configurations must be evaluated in order
>   to perform any resource type action, provider configurations may refer only to
>   values that are known before the configuration is applied.
>
> In particular,
>   avoid referring to attributes exported by other resources unless their values
>   are specified directly in the configuration.

For example, this would work (but not solve your problem):

```
variable "docker_host" {
  type = string
}

provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://${var.docker_host}:2376/"
}
```

But there is a way out.

The solution is made of two steps:

1. split your terraform configuration in two parts (each must reside in its own
   directory) where the one with the docker provider depends on the one that
   deploys the droplet. Note that this means that you will have to issue
   terraform commands separately (you need to apply twice).
2. Establish a unidirectional, read-only "connection" between the two states
   using a feature called [remote
   state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html):

> Retrieves state data from a Terraform backend. This allows you to use the
>   root-level outputs of one or more Terraform configurations as input data for another
>   configuration.

In you are not already using a "real" remote backend such as S3 + DynamoDB, you can still experiment easily using the [local backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/local.html) as follows.

Directory layout:

```
├── docker                   <== this performs docker operation
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── terraform.tfstate
└── server                   <== this deploys the droplet
    ├── main.tf
    └── terraform.tfstate
```

The snippets below are using AWS, but it is trivial to adapt to DO.

File server/main.tf contains something similar to

```
resource "aws_instance" "server" {     <= equivalent to the Droplet
  ...
}

output "ipv4_address" {
  value = aws_instance.server.public_ip
}
```

File docker/main.tf contains something similar to

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "docker_server" {
  backend = "local"

  config = {
    path = "${path.module}/../server/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://${data.terraform_remote_state.docker_server.outputs.ipv4_address}:2376/"
}
```

Finally:

```
cd server
terraform apply
cd ../docker
terraform apply
```

Remember: you have to perform also separate `terraform destroy`, in LIFO order:
first destroy `docker`, then destroy `server`.

Comment: This was very concise and helpful, I appreciate it.

Comment: Problem I'm having with this solution is that ssh won't work on server instance until you accept the ECDSA key fingerprint to known hosts which right now is manual

Comment: @lfmunoz the fact that SSH must be primed is unrelated to this solution. I suggest to start by reading  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Certificate-based_Authentication and ask a new question.

Comment: Isn't what @Hassan is trying to do similar to what is done [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#kubernetes-terraform-provider-example) (a kubernetes provider configuration depending on a created resource)?

Comment: Thanks, marco.m it really really helped me to solve my problem with cross-stack/directory referencing in terraform.